# Combo being editable C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++

I have a combo in my UI application which must not be editable. In other words I have few items in the drop down combo and user mus tbe able to drop down the combo when clicked anywhere on the combo. However somehow when i click on the arrow only the combo drops down. If I click anywhere in the combo the field becomes editable.

I dont want it to be editable. I know this must be simple. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the resource editor in VS, bring up the properties for the combo box. Change the "Type" property to "Drop List".

This is the GUI equivalent to the CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style that anand mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

See the example shown here: [CComboBox::Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh0cx55t%28VS.80%29.aspx). Also refer to combo box style CBS_DROPDOWNLIST.

Comment: Actually i use the GUI to form the combobox and dont explicitly do any create

Answer (score 1):

[You can look at this example for a readonly combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=6149).

Have a look at  `ReadOnlyComboBox.cpp`